# circuit breaker trips

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I have a breaker that keeps tripping even when no load is on it.  I have already replaced the breaker with a new one, replaced a ground fault outlet and a dimmer switch (all on that circuit), and the same thing happens.  There are two outlets I haven't checked and the light itself. Also I have checked for loose neutral wires at the panel. How do I find the problem?

Comment: Does it trip immediately or is it more intermittent?

Comment: I have located the problem. It was an outside light that has gotten water into it from too much snow.  I will be rewiring it in the spring.  For now it is disconnected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide an answer and accept it, or delete your question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the first step is to find out everything that's on this circuit, is the breaker a ground fault breaker or a regular breaker with a ground fault recepticle. If it's a regular breaker and you changed it, then it's not like an older one getting weak. So there has to be something else on this circuit drawing excess power. Flip the breaker off and start testing everything to see what's not working, recepticles as well. In the event the breaker is a ground fault breaker, you need to remove the ground fault recepticle.

Comment: Why would they have to remove the ground-fault receptacle?

Comment: If there's a ground fault breaker on the line feeding it adding a ground fault recepticle will not work as it is designed to and can continue to trip, if you really want the ground fault recepticle, take out the gfi breaker but the breaker is a lot more expensive. It's the same as feeding a second gfi recepticle off the gfi recepticle  already there, one will keep tripping needlessly, over use of gfi protection doesn't work.

Comment: There's should be no problem having a GFCI device downstream of another GFCI device, as long as both devices are properly wired.

Comment: I'm not here to go back and forth over things that are not recommended by the manufacturers, check it out yourself. It may look nice in a washroom to have each recepticle looking nice if each has a seperate feed but not all feeding on the one in front of each other on a single circuit...

Comment: @Richard, the reason you don't want to go back and forth over this is because you are wrong. Maybe if you stick to your trade of expertise you'd be better off.

Comment: Re: cascaded GFCIs -- the devices won't be *harmed* by it, it's simply a user nuisance as GFCI devices can't be coordinated, leading to a game of "who trips first?" when a ground fault happens.